# Setting KDE font size without Plasma desktop

Tags: kde, configuration

I am using some KDE applications (okular, konsole...), but without a KDE desktop environment (using fvwm). I want to increase font size in `~/.config/kdeglobals` but the settings there are ignored.

I have checked with `strace` that okular indeed accesses that config file.

$ cat ~/.config/kdeglobals

```
[General]
BrowserApplication[$e]=firefox.desktop
XftAntialias=true
XftHintStyle=hintmedium
XftSubPixel=none
desktopFont=Cantarell,22,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
fixed=Monospace,22,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
font=Cantarell,22,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
menuFont=Cantarell,22,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
smallestReadableFont=Cantarell,18,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
toolBarFont=Cantarell,18,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
widgetStyle=breeze

[Icons]
Theme=breeze

[Paths]
Desktop[$e]=$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)
Documents[$e]=$(xdg-user-dir DOCUMENTS)

[Toolbar style]
Highlighting=true
IconText=IconOnly
TransparentMoving=true

[WM]
activeFont=Cantarell,20,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

```
$ fc-list | grep Cantarell
```

```
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-VF.otf: Cantarell:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-VF.otf: Cantarell:style=Light
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-VF.otf: Cantarell:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-VF.otf: Cantarell
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-VF.otf: Cantarell:style=Extra Bold
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-VF.otf: Cantarell:style=Thin
```